# Trace of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $T$  is a linear operator on a complex vector space, $e_1 ,...,e_n$
>    is an orthonormal basis of $V$. Denote $M(T,e_1 ,...,e_n )=A={\{a_{j,k}\}}^n_{j,k=1} $.
>
> Then $A $ is an $n \times n$-matrix with complex entries. Show that $\text{trace} (A^∗ A)=∑^n_{j=1} ∑^n_{k=1} |a_{j,k}|^2$

Proof: Suppose that $T∈L(V)$  and $e_1 \dots e_n $  is an orthonormal basis of complex vector space V . Then, we have an upper triangular matrix. Then, $\|Te_1 \|^2 =|a_{1,1} |^ 2$

$\text{trace }(T∗T)=\langle T^∗Te_1 ,e_1 \rangle+\dots +\langle T^∗Te_n ,e_n \rangle \implies
\|Te_1 \|^2 +\dots+\|Te_n \|^2 $

Note that $\text{trace }T=\text{trace }A$.

Then 
$\text{trace}(A^∗A)=\|Te_1 \|^2 +\dots\||Te_n \|^2  
 \implies |a_{1,1} |^2 +\dots+|a_{n,n }|^2 =∑^n_{j=1} ∑^n_{k=1} |a_{j,k} |^2$

Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but I'll suggest a few tiny adjustments.  For that first series of inequalities, you should write
$$
trace(T^*T)=\langle T^*Te_1 ,e_1 \rangle+...+\langle T^*Te_n ,e_n \rangle 
\color{red}= \\
\color{red}{\langle Te_1,Te_1 \rangle +  \cdots + \langle Te_n,Te_n \rangle=}\\
||Te_1 ||^2 +...+||Te_n ||^2
$$
The $=>$ symbol is ambiguous and unnecessary.  Similarly, in that last equality, change $=>$ to $=$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment!I will do the adjustment!